# Is it possible to return the current object if it is an r-value reference?

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference

I have recently learned about r-value references. In order to more thoroughly experiment I decided to write a simple DenseMatrix class. My question is is it possible to write any function ( Transpose for this example ) such that for `auto A = B.Transpose()` separate matrix is returned, but for `auto A = (B + C).Transpose()` the result of the Transpose is calculated in place?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, you can overload the `Transpose` member function on the ref-qualification of the object it's being called on:

```
class DenseMatrix {
 
  DenseMatrix Transpose() const & {  // #1 called on l-values
     auto copy = *this;
     // transpose copy
     return copy;
  }

  DenseMatrix&& Transpose() && {  // #2 called on r-values
     // transpose *this
     return std::move(*this);
  }
};
```

So you get the result:

```
B.Transpose();        // calls #1
(B + C).Transpose();  // calls #2
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/TxE8nd).

Note that you could implement the l-value overload in terms of the r-value overload, like this:

```
DenseMatrix Transpose() const & {  
  auto copy = *this;
  return std::move(copy).Transpose();
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ThEWo9).

Comment: Why not `DenseMatrix&& Transpose() &&`? I.e. modifying an r-value in-place.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I thought of that, but it feels like copy elision would take care of that. I'm not sure though. Edited anyway, since it can't hurt at least.

Comment: @cigien `this` is a hidden function argument, and returning a function argument prevents return-value optimization and because `this` is not an object with automatic storage duration here. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision : _In a return statement, when the operand is the name of a non-volatile object with automatic storage duration, which isn't a function parameter or a catch clause parameter, and which is of the same class type (ignoring cv-qualification) as the function return type. This variant of copy elision is known as NRVO, "named return value optimization"._

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Aah, ok, that makes sense, thanks. It could still be optimized, but it's not guaranteed to.

Comment: Why there is `&&` after #2 `Transpose()`? I am unfamiliar with this syntax

Comment: It's the syntax that constrains the function to be called on r-values. In fact this syntax was introduced in c++11 to achieve exactly the effect you're looking for :)

Comment: @cigien where is this documented? I am googling and I can't find it.

Comment: @bar3 https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions#ref-qualified_member_functions

Comment: For a somewhat exhaustive general Q&A on ref-qualifiers, see [What does the & (ampersand) at the end of member function signature mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47002799/what-does-the-ampersand-at-the-end-of-member-function-signature-mean/47003980#47003980).