# How to create an if statement with two conditions using OR operation

Tags: c++, if-statement, logical-operators

I'm trying to make an if statement that can take in `if (input == "Cell" || "cell")` so i don't have to worry about the user typing it with a capital or not. But in the console, it seems to skip over the input command and go right past the if statement. I included a small snippet of where it goes wrong. Right when it gets to the first getline, it skips everything and goes to the else statement: "You are in the cell". Sorry if this doesnt make any sense, i dont know how else to describe it.

```
    while (gameRunning)//loop that keeps game running
    {
        std::getline(cin, input);//input which room the player wants to go to as input variable
        hud();

        if (input == "Cell" || "cell")//if statement controls all of room 1
        {
            inRoom1 = true;
            while (inRoom1 = true)
            {
                location = "Cell";
                hud();
                if (level >= 1)//executes if player has been in this room before
                {
                    typeText("*You don't find anything useful in the cell*\n");
                    location = "Main Hall";
                    inRoom1 = false;
                    hud();
                }
                else//executes if player has not been in this room before
                {
                    typeText("*You are in the cell*\n");
```

If I change the || into && then it doesnt skip past it. So im not really sure what is going wrong. I'm pretty new to coding so if you could give any tips it would be much appreciated.

Comment: `if (input == "Cell" || input == "cell")` `inRoom1 == false;` a few lines down is also incorrect and has no effect. You probably want a single `=` for assignment there. Be sure to turn up the warnings in whichever compiler you are using. Let it help you find the mistakes.

Comment: So, your edit made `while (inRoom1 = true)` incorrect since it is assigning true and then evaluating it. Don't edit the code as we point out mistakes.

Comment: `if (input == "Cell" || "cell")` -- In the C++ book you are using, do you see a comparison that looks like this?  I bet you can't find one.  The reason why is that this is not the way to compare if an item is either one or the other.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie That is why I asked, I am not using a book and I tried to find out the answer myself but couldn't find what I was looking for.

Comment: What about `CELL`, `cELL`, `ceLL` and all other permutations of character case? A more flexible (and clean) way to do this is to convert the string to lowercase, or use case-insensitive comparison. Plenty of options there include hand-rolling your own, using `std::transform`, non-standard C functions like `strcasecmp` or `stricmp`, or regular expressions.

Comment: Well, C++ isn't a language that can be learned by trial and error.  It is one of the most difficult computer languages out there.  See [the definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: The expression `input == "Cell" || "cell"` is equivalent to `input == ("Cell" || "cell")`.    When evaluating `"Cell" || "cell"`, both string literals are converted implicitly to a pointer, so `"Cell" || "cell"` will be evaluated as `true`.    So the expression `input == "Cell" || "cell"`  us the same as `input == true` (comparing a `std::string` with a `bool`).   Similar logic for `input == "Cell" && "cell"`.    Either way, the result does NOT test if `input` is equivalent to at least one of `"Cell"` or `"cell"`.  For that, do `input == "Cell" || input == "cell"`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, I'd say Python is one of the most difficult languages out there. It's scoping rules are weird, and side effects are nuts. You have to understand all the nuances of mutable vs immutable types.

Comment: @GabrielStaples   Naah.  Python has its quirks, but even subsets of C++ are much harder to learn properly than Python.   However, people with a background in Python, who start by assuming C++ works like Python (when it doesn't) demonstrate how easy it is to learn C++ *improperly*.

Comment: @LouisGo  A string literal like `"Cell"` is not a `const char *`.  String literals are implicitly converted to a `const char *` *in some contexts* (e.g. expressions) but not others (e.g.  `sizeof("Cell") != sizeof (const char *)`).

Comment: @Peter, yeah, you are right. C++ is totally nuts. See [my comment here and the ones underneath it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47002799/what-does-the-ampersand-at-the-end-of-member-function-signature-mean/47003980#comment109357350_47003980).